# Next 13 data fetching

Tags: next.js, next.js13

```
const getAccounts = async (): Promise<IAccountItem[]> => {
  const data = await fetchClient('/accounts');
  return Object.values(data.body);
};

const getProfile = async (): Promise<Profile> => {
  return await fetchClient('/auth/me');
};

export default async function AccountsPage() {
  const accounts = await getAccounts();
  const profile = await getProfile();

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.header}>
        <HeaderBlock accounts={accounts} profile={profile} />
        <NavMenu />
      </div>
      <AccountList accounts={accounts} />
    </>
  );
}
```

With this code in the Doc tab (Network tab dev tools) SSR disappears completely.
If you leave one query, everything goes back to normal
Next 13-14

Both of them work, and even if I try to put getProfile in the HeaderBlock component, it still doesn't work until I remove getAccounts, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the code you wrote is running as static site (SSG) is because your [fetch requests](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#caching-data) add the `cache: "force-cache"` directive by default.  You can do something like the following:

```js
const getAccounts = async (): Promise<IAccountItem[]> => {
  // never serves results from cache
  const data = await fetchClient('/accounts', { cache: "no-store" });
  return Object.values(data.body);
};

const getProfile = async (): Promise<Profile> => {
  // serves result from cache for 10 seconds
  return await fetchClient('/auth/me', { next: { revalidate: 10 } });
};
```

Either provide a default inside your `fetchClient` function that suits your needs or add a [segment configuration](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config) to apply the logic for a whole segment and all descending fetch requests.

```js
export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";
```

Comment: thanks, but its not helped me
I also saw some strange code in the response 
<div hidden id="S:1"> after loader html and js scripts

Comment: oh no, sorry, { next: { revalidate: 10 } } helped me